# Fake reviews datasets

Tags: nlp, spam, review, corpus

There are datasets with usual mail spam in the Internet, but I need datasets with fake reviews to conduct some research and I can't find any of them. 
Can anybody give me advices on where fake reviews datasets can be obtained?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our dataset is available on my Cornell homepage: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~myleott/

Answer (score 2):

A recent ACL paper, where the authors compiled such a data set:

```
Finding Deceptive Opinion Spam by Any Stretch of the Imagination
Myle Ott, Yejin Choi, Claire Cardie, Jeffrey T. Hancock
```

You might be able to find something in the references. Alternatively, you can mail the authors and check if the data are publicly available.