# Labeled dataset of product review spam

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, nlp, review

I've edited my question below after comment from @Tchotchke:
I am trying to train an NLP model to classify fake and authentic product reviews. For the training, I need a labeled dataset of such reviews. There are product review datasets published by researchers, but they aren't labeled. And some datasets (like the one in [Fake reviews datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588912/fake-reviews-datasets)) is for hotel reviews, and thus does not represent the wide range of language features that can exist for reviews of products like shoes, clothes, furniture, electronics, etc. that are sold on typical shopping portals like Amazon, Walmart, etc. Can someone please suggest a way to generate such a labeled dataset rather quickly or find one already available?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of amazon product review datasets provided by [UCSD](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/)

Comment: Thank-you @ryder1211212. But the dataset you mentioned is not labeled for fake/authentic. So, it does not serve my purpose. But thanks again.

Comment: @TDS did you eventually find such dataset ? I am also looking for something similar for my project , can you please point me towards the right direction.